# Parameter Date Conversion

Tags: visual-studio

am using C#, VS 2005 and SQL 2000

I have date conversion problem my SQL table having field as below

Fields:

```
datefrom    
dateto
```

My SQL query in C# is

```
string sql = "insert into companymast (cname, datefrom, dateto) values(@cname, @datefrom, @dateto)";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@cname",SqlDbType.Varchar(50)).Values = cname.text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@datefrom",SqlDbType.Datetime).Values = maskedTextBox1.text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dateto",SqlDbType.Datetime).Values = maskedTextBox2.text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But the above throw Error Like date non conversion string to date

I have to put date in `dd/MM/yyyy` format code, 103

so how do i do?

Help me out, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`maskedBox1.text` is a string. You're assigning that to a `SqlParameter`'s data member, and it tries to convert whatever it receives to the data type you request.

A more solid solution would be to convert to `DateTime` explicitly, and pass the converted value to the `SqlParameter`. This way, you have more control over the conversion, and you'll see exactly where and why it goes wrong when it does. Example:

```
DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Parse(maskedTextBox1.text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@datefrom",SqlDbType.Datetime).Values= fromDate;
```

For DateTime.Parse, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

Comment: Depends on the `CultureInfo` it uses, which in turn defaults to the current thread's culture, but can be overridden (details should be in the MSDN documentation). For user input, it is considered good practice to use the user's culture. If you want to be on the safe side, use a `Calendar` control instead of the `TextBox`, then you don't have to worry about the date's textual representation.